# Pyspark - Python3 get variable from file using configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, configparser

I am trying to get a variable from a file using Configparser but it always returns a string instead of a variable. Please assist

```
config.ini

[db]
connection_sting =sqlContext.read.format(driver).load(table_nm)

config_conn = ConfigParser() 
conn_string = config_conn.get('db', 'connection_sting')
```

Current result:

```
conn_string = 'sqlContext.read.format(driver).load(table_nm)'
```

Expected:

```
conn_string = sqlContext.read.format(driver).load(table_nm)
```

Comment: I don't think this `sqlContext.read.format(driver).load(table_nm)` should be in config.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't try. Configuration files are used to provide configuration options, not executable code.

Instead

`config.ini`

```
[db]
driver = some_format
table_nm = some_table
```

and

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

connection_sting = (sqlContext.read
    .format(config.get("db", "driver")
    .load(config.get("db", "table_nm")))
```

And in case when you need executable code use proper modules, not configuration.